# How to see the user who called the Pipeline Trigger Job in the Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I created with my user, one trigger in the Pipeline triggers of my project. I successfully executed the trigger and it appears on the job page. But since I want this trigger to be used by all developers on my team, I need to see who triggered the job. But always appears on the job page, that I, who created the trigger, triggered all jobs and not the other user who actually triggered it.

There is any way that can I show who triggered the job?

I tried to use, as another option the creating pipeline via API and setting a private token to each user. But when I pass a variable in the request, apparently the Gitlab API is not working with the variables option. Because, when we create a pipeline trigger and request it, we don't pass a user token, we pass the trigger token.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/52926

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to the repository that contains the CI Pipeline, under CI/CD>Pipelines there should be a table showing all past instances of the pipeline. There is a "Triggerer" column which should show you who triggered it.

If you are still unable to see who triggered it, perhaps you need to adjust your own [permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#gitlab-cicd-permissions)

Comment: When I go to the past instances of the pipeline, it shows that the pipeline that I triggered was not Triggered by me, it was triggered by the user that created the Trigger.

No matter who calls that trigger only shows in the Trigger column, the user who created the trigger.

Comment: Might be related to [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/42648). [This](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#taking-ownership-of-a-trigger) documentation states that "Each created trigger when run will impersonate their associated user including their access to projects and their project permissions." The [API doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipeline_triggers.html#take-ownership-of-a-project-trigger) indicates that the specific task id must be owned by an authenticated user. Read [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html)